# Creating a persistent updating notification in ionic vue

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, notifications, capacitor

Generally, after opening a/the clock app on a phone (at least on an  Android), and starting a stopwatch (or timer), when you minimize the app, or even close it, there's usually going to be a persistent notification with the current stopwatch/timer value that continuously updates.

[image]

[Here's an example GIF demonstrating this](https://gfycat.com/welloffjovialladybug)

As you can see, in the GIF, (linked above), even if I close the app, the notification displaying the current stopwatch value remains. I can't seem to find any info or examples on how I would do something like this with Ionic, or even if it's possible.

Both the Capacitor [LocalNotifications](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications#localnotificationschedule) plugin or the [Cordova one](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) have the option to schedule repeating notifications, but it doesn't seem like I can change the text value of the notification on each repetition.

I've also looked into the [BackgroundMode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode) plugin, thinking that maybe I could just keep sending new notifications each second from the background, but that only seems to allow me to run background tasks while the app is minimized, not when it's closed also.

So, is it even possible to display persistent updating notifications with Ionic, and if so, how?